# Bootstrap.css and jquery validation plugin for forms

Tags: css, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap with the jquery validation plugin but when I try to use bootstrap the error labels get put in front of the entries in my forms (pushing the entry to the right).  Secondly the validation only works on the first field of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"form-stacked" class for forms seemed to work with what I wanted.